# How can I loop through min and max values of my price table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table "Properties" and am retrieving the min and max price.
With those two values, I want a list of numbers from the min price up to the max price.
This is how I am trying:

```
Route::get('min', function(){
    $minprice = Property::min('price');
    $maxprice = Property::max('price');
    $min = (float)$minprice;
    $max = (float)$maxprice;
    for($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++){
        echo $i;
    }
})->name('min');
```

I used the float because the prices in my database are stored as a string.

If I echo the $min or $max I can see it fine.
When I make the get request I see nothing.
Anything wrong in my for loop?

Comment: Use `asort` or `arsort`? (not sure if your code is PHP)

Comment: Am using Laravel PhP framework

Comment: `prices in my database are stored as a string` then you won't get accurate value.

Comment: @ vivek_23 I do get an accurate value. Please see in my question a converted the string to float $min = (float)$minprice; and if I echo out I can see the value.
Just the for loo that does not work.

Comment: var_dump($i) inside loop and show us what it prints!

Comment: Your loop is wrong. $i++ increase $i to 1 every iteration. If your values are floats it is sens less. You need to use totally another approach to achieve what you want.

Comment: @deSousa What if values stored in DB are `100` and `2`. Do you get `max` as `100` or `2`? Have you provided any casting in your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try php function `range`.

```
Route::get('min', function(){
    $minprice = Property::min('price');
    $maxprice = Property::max('price');
    $min = $minprice;
    $max = $maxprice;

    foreach (range($min, $max, 1) as $number) {
        echo (float) $number;
    }

})->name('min');
```

**source:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: That works and appreciate the support.
Is there a reason why my for loop does not work?

Comment: @deSousa could you please upvote and mark checked? It will be very appreciated.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh but it will not show you actual prices from database, what is the sense?

Comment: @Volodymyr Please read question carefully. deSousa needs values from $min to $max with +1. Not values like 1, 5, 10, 41 etc. In database we may have not proper values in series. that's why he accepted my answer.

Comment: @LuckySaini my bad, get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('min', function(){

    // to get prices
    $prices = Property::all()->pluck('price');

    // To convert them to floats
    $floatPrices = array_map('floatval', $prices);

    // Sort and return them
    return asort($floatPrices);

})->name('min');
```

Comment: This would actually work. I am not sure how OP assumes that he/she would get right answers for `min` and `max` when all those values were stored as string.